# Unable to update Ubuntu 22.04 through command line

Tags: apt, upgrade, updates, wine

I'm trying to update my Ubuntu 22.04 with the command `sudo apt-get update`, but it shows following error:

```
sudo apt update
Hit:1 http://pk.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy InRelease
Hit:2 http://pk.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates InRelease
Hit:3 http://pk.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-backports InRelease
Ign:4 https://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable InRelease                                                   
Ign:5 https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/rael-gc/rvm/ubuntu jammy InRelease                                       
Ign:6 https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubu... eoan InRelease                                                   
Ign:7 http://packages.microsoft.com/repos/code stable InRelease                                            
Ign:8 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security InRelease             
Hit:8 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security InRelease                                                
Hit:7 http://packages.microsoft.com/repos/code stable InRelease                                                 
Hit:5 https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/rael-gc/rvm/ubuntu jammy InRelease                                       
Hit:4 https://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable InRelease                               
Ign:6 https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubu... eoan InRelease         
Err:9 https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubu... eoan Release
  404  Not Found [IP: 199.232.46.217 443]
Reading package lists... Done
E: The repository 'https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubu... eoan Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

Comment: @user535733 not working this way...

Comment: "not working" is vague: Unclear what you did and what failed. Try to be more specific.  [Edit your question](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1430190/edit) to add more information; comments are NOT a chat thread. You asked where the PPA source is located: It's located in one of the files within the `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/` directory.

Comment: your mentioned path doesn't have any file/directory.

Comment: Edit your question to show the complete output of the command `cat /etc/apt/sources.list.d/*` AND the complete output of `sudo apt update`